# how to move a grafana panel from bottom to top without exchanging the top one with the bottom?

Tags: grafana

I have 30 grafana panels in a dashboard.  If I add a new one to bottom and then drag it to top it replaces the panel which was in the top to be in the bottom which is totally what I don't want I want it to be inserted and the top panel to move to the right or left, is that possible?

Comment: If you have 30 panels in the same row, methinks you might benefit from multiple rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: you can't

Workaround: first duplicate or add an empty panel at the top, then drag and drop on top of it. Last remove the duplicated or empty panel at the bottom.

Comment: sounds good only empty panels are created at the bottom, i cant create empty panel at top